# If dealing with arrays, what would be a basic way to go about my exercise with if/else conditionals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

***EDIT!!!!!!!!***

My apologies on the whole thing everyone. I'm clearly just getting started and because of that, I tend to get a little tongue tied on the issues I'm having with programming. What I meant to ask was a proper format to use if/else statements on functions utilizing loops. Again, my apologies.

I'm currently going through different scenarios and exercises for arrays. Nothing too fancy, what I'm doing are different ways to iterate through each array I create. The array in question is this.

```
var listofKen = ['Ken', 'Kenny', 'Kenneth', 'ken', 'kenjamin', 'kendonesia'];
```

I've already tried out different ways of looping through this. I've even added a function declaration and put a for loop through it. Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
function loopThroughThis () {
for (var i = 0; i < listofKen.length; i++) {
listofKen[i] = console.log(listofKen[i]);
};
```

Then I simply call the function down below with this..

```
loopThroughThis();
```

Boom, it iterates but I want to try to combine this with an if/else scenario. What I want to do is simply just have this kind of situation played out.....

If the function of loopThroughThis() is to take hold and it works, how could I add an if/else conditional statement to show that the loopThroughThis function is valid/true and can loop through the array created. If it's true and the function works, execute the function and iterate through the array with the for loop I've created. Should this not be true, console.log 'Kenneth you need a lot more studying to do';

Comment: What does it mean for `loopThroughThis` to “work”, exactly? What do you mean by “can loop through the array created”? When could it not? Do you know about [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: check out [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array#every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: Your question is not understandable. What does "take hold" mean? What does it mean for "the `loopThroughThis` function to be "valid/true"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps, should help you with if/else statements:

```js
var listofKen = ['Ken', 'Kenny', 'Kenneth', 'ken', 'kenjamin', 'kendonesia'];

function loopThroughThis() {
    var somoneNeedsToStudy = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < listofKen.length; i++) {
        var kenVal = listofKen[i];
        if ( shouldKenStudyMore(kenVal) ) {
            console.log('Kenneth you need a lot more studying to do.');
        } else {
            somoneNeedsToStudy= true;
            console.log('You\'ve studied long enough ' + kenVal);
        }
    }
    return somoneNeedsToStudy;
}

function shouldKenStudyMore(ken) {
    if ( ken === 'Kenneth' ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    //Above could also be written as "return ken === 'Kenneth';"
}

if ( loopThroughThis() ) {
    console.log('Someone needed to study');
}
```